# Proper way to validate uniqueness_of for multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Let's say I have this unique index on a table:

```
add_index :events, [:venue_id, :act_id, :occurs_on], :unique => true
```

Now if I want to validate this in the model, should I do this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :venue_id, :scope => [:act_id, :occurs_on]
```

or this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :venue_id, :scope => [:act_id, :occurs_on]
validates_uniqueness_of :act_id, :scope => [:venue_id, :occurs_on]
validates_uniqueness_of :occurs_on, :scope => [:venue_id, :act_id]
```

Comment: Your second statement is the equivalent of "given a particular :act_id and :occurs_on, :venue_id should be unique". In order words, it is actually less strict than `validates_uniqueness_of :venue_id`, as it allows for events with the same `:venue_id` as long as the other two columns aren't the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first uniqueness constraint translates to "There can only be one of any particular venue_id, act_id, and occurs_on tuple in the table." Therefore only the first validation statement should be necessary.